# Use and register multiple ASP.NET mvc3 solutions on 1 website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've read about Areas and know how to use them.
But is there another way to use a completed web application in mvc 3 and put it in a different mvc 3 application and acces it?

Or run 2 different solutions on one host?

mysite/1stapplication
mysite/2ndapplication

The same way areas work but with multiple completed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No, each web application is a different one. At most, you can share aseemblies between them but the asp.net mvc projects themselves will be considered separate applications. If you want in fact to host them at the same address, then it's possible. Just put each app in a virtual directory on the server.